# list property containing two types (string/int)

Tags: c#

I need to have a property that will be an array that can hold both ints and strings.
if i set the property to an array of ints it should be ints so when I am searching through this array the search will be fast, and at odd times this property will also contain strings which the search will be slow.
Is there any other way other than the following to have a list that contain native types

1. two properties one for ints and one for strings
2. use List< object >

**UPDATE:**
The use-case is as follow.  I have a database field [ReferenceNumber] that holds the values (integers and strings) and another field [SourceID] (used for other things) which can be used to determine if record holds an int or string.

I will be fetching collections of these records based on the source id, of course depending on what the source is, the list either will be integers or strings.  Then I will go through this collection looking for certain reference numbers, if they exist not add them or they dont then add them.  I will be pre-fetching a lot of records instead of hitting the database over and over.

so for example if i get a list for sourceid =1 that means they are ints and if searching i want the underline list to be int so the search will be fast. and if sourceid say is 2 which means they are strings and very rare its okay if the search is slow because those number of records are not that many and a performance hit on searching through strings is okay.

Comment: create a class then from there have a `List<ClassObject>` || create something like a Dictionary or KeyValuePair `var someList= new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();`

Comment: Maybe if you elaborate on the needs of your particular case we could suggest a third option.

Comment: Or you can go with `List<Tuple<int, string>>`

Comment: @fmarreco I would probably go with `List<Tuple<int?, string>>`

Comment: Tuple would be really awesome but do you think that `Zonky` knows what a tuple is...?

Comment: updated the original with more details

Comment: In your update you mention "Searching the list fast" how do you plan on doing that?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I will be using .Find or what ever method is available on the collection to determine if an item exists (assuming .find on a int array is faster than on a string array) which is why am doing this in the first place

Comment: @Zoinky: That sounds like a premature optimization. Until you've determined that this is an actual performance problem, I'd stick with the simplest approach possible.

Comment: Why do you think calling `Find` on a int array is faster than on a string array? Also does location matter? if it does not just the fact that the item is in the collection then using a `HashSet<string>` may be a better solution and don't attempt to convert the string numbers in to real numbers at all.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain my previous test on other string vs int collections prove that there is a difference in seek time so that is why that assumption was made.  The location matters in this case because the prefetched collection will not be used to add to it.. another collection will be used to keep track of the ones that do not exist in the database then alot of stuff happens in between.. before these records are added to database..

Comment: @Zoinky I think if you updated your question to show actual code of what you are doing you will get a lot better help. The current way you are describing your project it is hard to follow what you are explaining.

Comment: @Zoinky: Did you figure out a solution to this?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior moved on to more issues.. will revisit this once I solve it. Although keeping it just as string is pretty fast enough so I may just not care and make it all just strings instead of ints where they are ints.

Comment: @Zoinky: If performance was the only reason you were trying to use ints, then that's probably a good idea. Use types that represent your logic model.

Answer (score 2):

> I will go through this collection looking for certain reference numbers, if they exist not add them or they dont then add them.

It sounds to me like you don't need a `List<>`, but rather a `HashSet<>`. Simply use a `HashSet<object>`, and `Add()` all the items, and the collection will ignore duplicate items. It will be super-fast, regardless of whether you're dealing with `int`s or `string`s.

On my computer, the following code shows that it takes about 50 milliseconds to populate an initial 400,000 unique strings in the hashset, and about 2 milliseconds to add an additional 10,000 random strings:

```
var sw = new Stopwatch();
var initial= Enumerable.Range(1, 400000).Select(i => i.ToString()).ToList();
sw.Start();
var set = new HashSet<object>(initial);
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
var random = new Random();
var additional = Enumerable.Range(1, 10000).Select(i => random.Next(1000000).ToString()).ToList();
sw.Restart();
foreach (var item in additional)
{
    set.Add(item);
}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Also, in case it's important, `HashSet<>`s *do* retain order of insertion.

Comment: Important note, whatever class you are putting in the hashset make sure it implements `GetHashCode()` and `Equals` (`string` and `int` both do, but if you use a custom class it won't unless you program it)

Answer (score 0):

The only other thing I would suggest is a custom object that implements IComparable

```
class Multitype: IComparable
{
   public int? Number { get; set; }
   public string Words {get; set; }

   public int CompareTo(object obj)
   {
       Multitype other = obj as Multitype;
       if (Number != null && other != null && other.Number != null)
       {
           //...
       }
       else
       {
           //...
       }
   }
}
```

There will be some extra comparison steps between numbers, but not as much as string parsing.

Are you storing a ton of data, is that performance difference really going to matter?

Comment: There is a lot of data to be searched through, the prefetch of ints  collection will probably be around 400k and I will be checking about 10k against these each time, the strings maybe 10k, searching about 2k against them

Answer (score 0):

If by "use List" you mean the object primitive or provided `System.Object`, that is an option, but I think it would behoove you to make your own wrapper object -- `IntString` or similar -- that would handle everything for you. It should implement `IComparable`, as the other gal mentioned.

You can increase the efficiency of sorting your object in collections by writing a `CompareTo` method that does exactly what you need it to. Writing a good `CompareTo` method is a whole can of worms in itself, so you should probably start a new question for that, if that's what you want.

If you're looking for a property that is strongly typed as a `List<Int>` or `List<String>` at instantiation, but can change afterwards, then you want an interface. `IList` exists, but won't help you, since that must also be strongly typed upon declaration. You should probably make something like `IIntStringList` that can only be one of `List<Int>` or `List<String>`.

Sorry this answer doesn't have that many details (I need to leave the office now), but I hope I've set you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use generics if you implement them on the class. Not sure if this solves your problem. Would be interested to hear the real-world example of a property that can have different types.

```
class Foo<T>
{
    public List<T> GenericList { get; set; }

    public Foo()
    {
        this.GenericList = new List<T>();
    }
}
```

Comment: I just deleted my own answer that suggested this same approach, since I saw that the updated question probably involves more of a run-time solution.